# Is it possible to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event on an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection and I would like to do something when the collection is changed.

```
private ObservableCollection<myType> _oc = new ObservableCollection<myType>();

public MyConstructor()
{
    _oc.CollectionChanged += myEventHandler();
}

private System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler myEventHandler()
{
    //myCode
}
```

But the code in myEventHandler is not execute.

How could I do that?

Thank so much.

Comment: Yes, that should work. How do you know the collection changed?

Comment: You mean that `myEventHandler` doest not execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of your handler seems off. Could you try something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<myType> _oc = new ObservableCollection<myType>();

public MyConstructor()
{
    _oc.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
}

private void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //myCode
}
```

And obviously add something to the collection so you can test the event.

```
_oc.Add(new myType());
```